# block google chrome extension with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is it possible to block Chrome extensions Like temperMonkey with ajax or JavaScript or another framework?

because the users use tampermonkey to cheat  example

or block by extension id or this dir 
chrome-extension://dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo/userscript.html?id=34a9d065-226d-4fc5-9f76-77e2745f96cb

any ideas ?